# New SSD not recognised by new laptop

Tags: laptop, ssd, bios, nvme, acer

I have just bought a new laptop (an Acer Swift 314-512-56QM) with the intention of upgrading the SSD with one the I already own (an Adata XPG SX8200 Pro - 2TB). However the replacement drive is not recognised when installed internally, and I would really appreciate any advice people may have.

The drive sometimes appears in the BIOS, but usually does not, and either way it never shows when booting from a Windows installation USB, either as an available drive in the Windows installation wizard or even in diskpart when run from command line.

There could conceivably be a driver issue - certainly the trackpad is non-functional as well during the Windows installation - however after downloading additional drivers for this laptop from the Acer website these got the trackpad working but not the hard drive. And in any case I would have expected diskpart to see the disk even if Windows had a driver issue.

It works perfectly when connected via a caddy and USB, and works perfectly when installed in my old laptop (also an Acer Swift 3, but an older model).

It is currently formatted with GPT and NTFS.

I believe the drive should be supported in the laptop, the drive is PCIe Gen3x4 and NVMe 1.3, although it is hard to find exact technical details about the laptop. The motherboard seems to be a "HH4U4 LA-M191P" according to what's printed on the board, however knowing that hasn't helped me much.

I have also tried a second SSD which I have available, a SK hynix BC511 HFM256GDJTNI-82A0, and that isn't recognised either.

The original SSD which came pre-installed in the new laptop is always recognised and boots into Windows with no problems. I haven't run through the initial Windows setup on that drive yet, but doubt that would be the issue. That drive is a Micron 2450 512GB (MTFDKBA512TFK), which is the same: m.2 2280, NVMe 1.3.

I'm completely at a loss, and would be really grateful if anyone is able to help determine what's wrong here!

Comment: Just a comment, while you continue with troubleshooting, also consider finding out from Acer Tech support what is the Max size of NVMe SSD supported by the laptop model.

Comment: Thanks so much, I did try a 256Gb one which didn't work. Also, although it's no guarantee, the 2Tb one was in a previous model Acer Swift 3 so it feels unlikely that they will have reduced the maximum capacity in a more recent model. I am hoping to speak to Acer customer support anyway once they open though, and will ask that too.

Comment: You may need to update UEFI.

Comment: Thanks guys, on further investigation it sounds like this Acer model does indeed not support SSDs over 1Tb - thanks!